# Objects that don't support custom buttons (WebLinks)

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api, custom-button, metadata

I'm writing code that uses the metadata API to deploy a custom button (WebLink) to all CustomObjects in my Salesforce org. I just list out all objects wit a listMetadata and then do a retrieve and deploy on all the objects in the list.

However, there are several objects that don't seem to support custom buttons:
CollaborationGroup, Pricebook2, PricebookEntry, TimeSlot, CollaborationGroup, CreditMemoLine, InvoiceLine

If these objects don't support buttons, that is fine by me, but then I need something to identify via the api that they don't support it so I can skip them when creating my deployment package.
I do not ant to make a hard coded list of objects to skip.

Any ideas how I can identify which objects do not support custom buttons?